# Python meta/unpacking in a function

Tags: python, syntax, meta

I have a function (func1) that returns a 4-tuple of mixed strings and integers. I want to immediately pass these 4 values into a second function (func2). This is how I am doing it now:

```
var1, var2, var3, var4 = func1(input1)
func2(var1, var2, var3, var4)
```

Functions don't unpack tuples when given as input, so this code is broken:

```
func2(func1(input1))
```

Is there a pythonic way to implement this code in the style of the second code block so func2 will unpack the values or some equivalent?

Comment: `func2(*func1(input1))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`* operator`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2921847/2096752):

```
func2(*func1(input1))
```